# Gmail blue links in email

Tags: css, html-email, zurb-ink

I can't figure out how to change these blue links Gmail is adding to the email I'm trying to code.

I've searched online and implemented their fixes but to no avail.

[image: See here]

Here's my code.

```html
<th class="small-12 large-6 last columns text-right show-for-large" valign="middle" style="Margin:0 auto;color:#fff;font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;padding:0;padding-bottom:16px;padding-left:8px;padding-right:16px;padding-top:16px;text-align:right;width:274px">
    <a href="https://website.com/wealth" style="Margin:0;color:#fff!important;font:inherit;font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;font-size:10px!important;font-weight:400;line-height:1.75;margin:0;padding:0;pointer-events:none;text-align:left;text-decoration:none!important">​Wealth</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <a href="https://discover.website.io/" style="Margin:0;color:#fff!important;font:inherit;font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;font-size:10px!important;font-weight:400;line-height:1.75;margin:0;padding:0;pointer-events:none;text-align:left;text-decoration:none!important">​News</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <a href="https://website.com/contact" style="Margin:0;color:#fff!important;font:inherit;font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;font-size:10px!important;font-weight:400;line-height:1.75;margin:0;padding:0;pointer-events:none;text-align:left;text-decoration:none!important">​Contact Us</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</th>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gmail stripping link color from emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110327/gmail-stripping-link-color-from-emails)

Comment: And it's weird that it only happen to one of the links while the other links seem to be fine. Perhaps there's something else causing this? Like a plugin or something installed on your browser?

Comment: @Vega the Margin is a fix for outlook apparently.

Comment: @AlonEitan I've tried looking at it on two different browsers and same issue.

Comment: @Peekay So please check the solution in the suggested duplicate - See if it helps

Comment: @AlonEitan I've tried the fix suggested in the other post.  If I change the color to color:#000001!important;, it works.  Obviously it does not show because the background is black.  If I change it #fffffff, I get the same problem.

Comment: @Peekay You have 7 `f`s there (`#fffffff`) It must be 3/6 (`#fff` or `#ffffff`)

Comment: @AlonEitan, tried changing to color to off white (#f7f7f7) and still getting the same issue.  I hate email development!

Comment: @AlonEitan still getting the same issue after fixing the hex code.

Comment: @Peekay Sorry, but I'm out of ideas. The only thing I can think of is more testing & debugging  - Try changing the link, change the text, change the structure (Wrap the text with a `span` and give the span `color:#ffffff;`) and so on... It should work with the details you provided and I don't know why it doesn't

Comment: @AlonEitan Appreciate the help.  Thanks bud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a `<span>` tag around the links to get it working per Alon's suggestion in the comments.

Comment: When the timer expires be sure to mark this as the accepted answer (click the checkmark) so that others know it solved your problem!

Answer (score 1):

So for gmail in order to pick up the an actual style for a hyperlink anchor (  ) you have to use the following inline css to set the colour and remove the underlining : 
`style="color: #FF0000; text-decoration:none; cursor:text; pointer-events: none;"`

This is how a complete tag would look like :
`<a href="http://www.google.com/" style="color: #FF0000; text-decoration:none; cursor:text; pointer-events: none;">Click here to go to Google</a>`

This works as of date answered : 19/09/2019

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to change the colours the 6 digit values, I don't think any email clients support 3 digit colours. I'd also remove all the inline styles on the a tags apart from `color` & `text-decoration`, also drop the `!important`. The font styling will all be inherited from the `th`.

An overall css fix I use in all templates is below. You'll also need to add an id="body" to your `<body>` element.

```
    u+#body a,
    #MessageViewBody a {
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: inherit;
      font-family: inherit;
      font-weight: inherit;
      line-height: inherit;
    }
```

(`#MessageViewBody a` will remove blue links from Samsung Mail too, no need to add that ID into your code though. A handy fix to have.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.